# QGIS is slow and vectors have low resolution

Tags: qgis, resolution

I have a new, alright laptop (16GB RAM, nVidia GeForce mx450, 3.3 GHz i7) and QGIS has worked very smoothly so far, even when working with massive files. But recently, quite suddenly, QGIS became much slower at rendering than I have ever experienced. Soon after that it started having very low resolution as well, mostly visible on basemaps and vector layers (especially labels, which are barely readable). It could have something to do with the rendering settings I changed to increase speed, although nothing changes now when I change the rendering settings back. So right now the resolution is terrible and at the same time rendering speed slow still (however a bit faster than it was recently): If I zoom in or out, or pan around, the map disappears (everything becomes white) for a few seconds and then loads each layer one at a time for a few seconds. This is with just a basemap and one simple vector layer, it can load for 10+ seconds after zooming, if I have more layers visible.

Please see attached pictures of settings  + resolution.

I've tried updating, reinstalling, creating new profile, anything I can imagine. I've tried versions 3.16, 3.22, 3.24 - makes no difference. I have checked the computer's graphic card settings to make sure that QGIS uses the nVidia card and not the integrated one.  Any idea what this can be due to and how to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please define "rendering speed is very slow". Have you tried resetting your preferences to default? Did you change something else on your laptop? Did you connection change? etc pp

Comment: Some OS and/or graphic card allow to set different graphical/rendering setting for each software, maybe you inadvertently set your configuration to a minimal setting for QGIS...

Comment: are you sure you are rendering vectors? this looks very much like a online background map which comes as raster.

Comment: I assume your problem also occurs in new projects tested with some of the same vector and basemap data.  I assume when you created a new profile you tested it without any added plugins first, but a new profile might not change some registry settings.  You might remove the profile and all QGIS registry entries and then the program itself before reinstalling.  Another option if you used the network install is to install the windows package, or vice versa.  They can be installed at the same time but use different folders.

Comment: Also in the Canvas & Legend tab of the option setting there is a "Respect screen DPI" tickbox (QGIS 3.24) you may try to change this setting